# What property is alert showing me?

Tags: javascript, object, alert

When I am writing Javascript, I use window.alert() to debug. Usually I pass variables to alert and it pops up with a string containing that variables value. However, if I pass alert an object, it tells me the type of the object. For example:

```
var form = document.getElementById("my_form");
alert(form); // returns [object HTMLFormElement]
```

That bit, the part that says [object blah blah]. What property is that? I have recently started making my own objects to encapsulate useful parts of the site I am working on... but when I pass my own objects to alert it gives me the generic message [object Object], which is not very helpful if I have made a bunch of different kinds of object. I would prefer, for instance, my object to return to me something more along the lines of [object My_Object].

Is there a property I can set in function My_Object() that will tell alert what I want it to tell me?

Thanks!

z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try redefining "toString()" of your class prototype: it's used to create a string type of an object. Default it's `[object <type>]`, but that's not what you want, is it.

Though, "You can override this method for custom objects that you create. If you do not override toString in a custom object, toString returns `[object type]`, where type is the object type or the name of the constructor function that created the object.", http://www.synchro.net/docs/js/ref/object.html#1193350

Comment: just changing "type" didn't work... But writing a quick toString method was fine!

Answer (score 6):

You must overwrite the `toString()` method. Otherwise, `Object.prototype.toString` will be used, which returns `"[object Foo]"`, where `Foo` is the value of the internal (ie inaccessible) class property of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of debugging with alert(), you should look at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), and outstanding web development tool, with better HTML inspection, javascript debugging, and other goodies.

Comment: +1. Or the WebKit Web Inspector (in Safari and Chrome) or the IE 8 Developer Toolbar, or Opera Dragonfly, or Firebug Lite for older browsers.